# SAS: What does the last two result columns (in outstats= of Proc Compare mean?

Tags: sas

I have the following `proc compare` in SAS:

```
proc compare METHOD=ABSOLUTE CRITERION=0.0001 BRIEFSUMMARY
    base=win.&table.
    compare=lin.&table.
    outstats=&table.1
    OUTNOEQUAL outbase outcomp ;
run;
```

This gives me the following table `outstats` where the last two columns read `Statistic for Difference Values` and `Statistic for Percent Difference Values`

[image]

**What do these two last columns mean?** I have the same values for `max` and `min`, so I expect to have 0 in these columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third column contains statistics for `compare_value - base_value`, the fourth contains statistics for `(compare_value - base_value) / base_value`

To fully understand it, try

```
data BASE_DATA (rename=(base_value=value) drop=comp_value) COMP_DATA (rename=(comp_value=value) drop=base_value);
    infile datalines truncover;
    Input base_value 5.1 comp_value 5.1;
    datalines;
 10.0 10.0
 10.0 15.0
 15.0 10.0
 15.0 15.0
;
title merged data;
data mrg;
    merge BASE_DATA (rename=(value=base_value)) COMP_DATA (rename=(value=comp_value));
    differ = comp_value - base_value;
    prcent = differ / base_value;
    format prcent percentn8.1;
proc print data=mrg;
run;

title comparison statistics;
proc compare METHOD=ABSOLUTE CRITERION=0.0001 BRIEFSUMMARY noprint
    base=BASE_DATA compare=COMP_DATA
    outstats=stats
    OUTNOEQUAL outbase outcomp ;

proc print data=stats;
run;
```

Also change the values in the datalines to

```
 10.0 11.0
-10.0-11.0
-10.0-11.0
 10.0 11.0
```

or

```
xxxxx 10.0
 10.0 15.0
 15.0yyyyy
  0.0 15.0
```

or

```
 10.0  0.0
 10.0 20.0
 10.0  0.0
 10.0 20.0
```

or whatever you like.

Comment: So for MAX I have 10.6 - 10.6 = 1?

Comment: Not at all try a few experiments using the code I add now, changing the values of the datalines